# Background Process to scan the location of the user at regular intervals and update the local database even when the app is not open

Tags: java, android, service, background-process, intentservice

I am creating an app that checks for user locations every half an hour and updates the location of the user in the local database and then runs CRUD queries based on the user's location even when the app is not running. How do i do it ?

I have referred to this http://techtej.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html article and i am still confused about which is the correct approach for my result ?

There are 4 options according to the article for what i intend to achieve according to me

1) Service : But since i feel it would be a long operation with the local database, i feel i should ignore this one.

2) IntentService : This cannot perform multiple tasks, so i feel this one also should be avoided for me as i have to get the location of the user and scan the database , update the database (3 tasks)

3)Thread : I am not sure how to call this when the app is not open

4) AsyncTask :  I am not sure how to call this when the app is not open.

Basically i looking for something like a CRON JOB that runs on a local database while working on the location data.

It would be great if you could link me up to some tutorials and answer with a simple example to make me understand the difference of all 4 methods.

// editted on 16 March : 
I have read something about a JobScheduler which is introduced in the API 21, but not sure if it also supports till Gingerbread and is it the right approach for my question

Thanx

Answer (score 4):

When recording the users position use a service with a notification.  Just for the sake of creating a morally responsible app that informs the user the app is tracking them.  The service by definition runs in the background.

A fused location provider with `setinterval(long)` `30 minutes` gets the interval.  Set `fastestInterval()` to a minute to receive GPS data when other apps are using the GPS.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a SyncAdapter. Its best to schedule jobs at fixed interval and also optimized for battery usage. Also, once started, it can run independently of the app. As per your requirements, I believe this is best suited for your need. You can read about this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html). This also removes the corner case of starting the service (generally used) when your device is restarted. Your app will still continue running the scheduled job even if the device gets restarted.

In the SyncAdapter you have to use a ContentProvider so wrap your DB inside a ContentProvider. Also, preferably use a CursorLoader to run longrunning tasks on DB. You should read about [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html). This is a great way to access your resources. Also, you can define an Observer Design Pattern which Observes for changes in a DB and will perform a task when changes are made in DB. This can also be used inside your application itself and also inside SyncAdapter. Cursor Loader is best preferred for background work on DB. You can perform all CRUD Operations using a CursorLoader and ContentProvider.

Answer (score 3):

> This cannot perform multiple tasks

Yes, it can. It has only one thread, and so it can only do one *simultaneous* task.

> i have to get the location of the user and scan the database , update the database (3 tasks)

I have no idea why you think that is three tasks. You cannot do them simultaneously.

Your bigger problem with `IntentService` is that getting location data is asynchronous, and `IntentService` is not well-suited for calling APIs that themselves are asynchronous.

> But since i feel it would be a long operation with the local database, i feel i should ignore this one.

The *point* behind *any* service is for "a long operation".

> Basically i looking for something like a CRON JOB that runs on a local database while working on the location data

Use `AlarmManager` to trigger a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, which then triggers a `Service`. The `Service`, in `onStartCommand()`, forks a background thread to (asynchronously) retrieve the location and update the database. The `Service` can then call `completeWakefulIntent()` on `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, plus `stopSelf()` with the `startId` received in `onStartCommand()` for this work, plus allow the thread to terminate. If no other commands were received in the interim, the service will shut down.

Comment: Could you please help me with this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300157/push-notifications-not-received-by-everyone

Comment: could u help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947115/how-to-implement-an-action-bar-like-google-maps

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something similar to [WakefulIntentService](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful). This handles all your cases completely.

You can do your location and db related work inside doWakefulWork() of said implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I've done what you are looking for, both with GPS and non-GPS.

The project I took as staring point for the non-GPS solution already does all you need, and is battery-friendly (credits should go to Kenton Price):

https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

Take a look at it, it works like a charm. Just run it in any device. If you need any help customizing just let me know.

Just edit the "onReceive" method in the "TestBroadcastReceiver" to update your DB.

If you need the GPS solution let me know too, but I dropped it for being a battery killer!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I think for this requirement, **Thread and inside it AsyncTask** -- this structure will be useful.

In link provided by you, it is mentioned very nicely [here](http://techtej.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html)

**2.** For location related blog, you can check useful materials here :

(1) [Difference between Google Map Distance and Directions API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28956350/1994950)

(2) [Check this answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29008065/1994950)

Hope this will help you