# How to implement an action bar like google maps

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image]I've been looking around but I can't seem to find out how to implement an action bar that looks like the one in Google maps and Google now. Can anyone give me a link to a documentation/tutorial or at least the name of that type of action bar?

Edit:I've attached a picture of what i want the action bar to look like

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've solved this myself. I hid the default actionbar and used XML to create the custom actionbar(using linearlayout, EditText and Buttons).